# Haven't touched this project because it was so laggy. I managed to make the low poly the same amount as the high poly?

Tags: modeling, rendering, baking

[image: I suppose I overdid it with the subdivision and multi res modifiers. How can I fix it?]

I suppose I overdid it with the subdivision and multi res modifiers. How can I fix it? The file is over 1kb

Comment: You said that "I suppose I overdid it with the subdivision and multi res modifiers" So did you try lowering the values?

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Decimate modifier on it.
The un-subdivide mode will revert the levels of subdivision if you applied a subdivide or multires modifiers:
[image]

The collapse mode will merge the faces and reduce the count while respecting the general shape of the object as much as possible:
[image]

Choose one depending on whether your object is just a simple shape that has been subdivided too many times or an object with relatively flat faces and some small detail sculpted on it.
(Planar mode does the same as collapse but with ngon faces so I don't think it's very useful)

Comment: Thank you! After I do this, would I have to do retopology again? If so, should I save the low poly into a new file after - so it's separate from the high poly model, reducing the file size?

Comment: You can take the lower res object, give it a multires mod and shrinkwrap to have the same shape as the high poly mesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx835KV4aZg
But I don't see how that's going to lower your geometry count if you are still gonna add a multi res modifier to it again